# Data Factory is getting � instead of á or é, or any other character with acute

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Data Factory is getting � instead of á or é, or any other character with acute, even when the default encoding for the source (which is a .csv file in a blob storage) is UTF-8 (characters with acute are supported by this encoding) and the data type of the destination (which is a sql database in azure) is nvarchar.

Is this a known issue? any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution was adding:
 "encodingName": "Windows-1252"
in the format properties of the source.

For some reason, it works properly with this encoding.